# How do I place a door?

Tags: fallout-4

I'm trying to place a door, and nowhere seems to be a valid place. Do I need something else before to place it against? I've built a small basic square 4 walled structure, with a gap left a little wider than the door.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Doors will only fit within specified structures, you don't put them between two other structures. For example:

[image: placing a door]

Other examples of the structures you can fit doors to include these two, plus the various entryways in the prefabs:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Doors can only be placed in walls that have an opening for a door, you can't leave a gap and place a door in there.

When you are placing walls, scroll over to the right and you will see some that leave an opening for a door, use those walls if you want to place a door there later.